# psycopg2 PSQL SELECT statement returning 0L instead of 0

Tags: python-2.7, psycopg2, psql

I'm having an unexpected result from my SELECT statement.

I have the following code:

```
db_cursor.execute("""SELECT player.player_id, player.player_name, 
                       COUNT(match.winner_id) as wins, COUNT(match.loser_id + match.winner_id) as total_matches
                       FROM player LEFT JOIN match ON player.player_id = match.winner_id
                       GROUP BY player.player_id
                       ORDER BY wins ASC""")
results = db_cursor.fetchall()
print results
```

And i get the following output when I print.

```
[(317, 'Bruno Walton', 0L, 0L), (318, "Boots O'Neal", 0L, 0L), (319, 'Cathy Burton', 0L, 0L), (320, 'Diane Grant', 0L, 0L)]
[(318, "Boots O'Neal", 0L, 0L), (320, 'Diane Grant', 0L, 0L), (317, 'Bruno Walton', 1L, 1L), (319, 'Cathy Burton', 1L, 1L)]
```

What is the 0L and 1L? I thought the 'L' was only for really large numbers, rather than a single digit.

Sorry, I'm a beginner so it might be really obvious, but any help would be appreciated. If it helps, this is the psql for the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS player
(player_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, player_name TEXT);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS match
(match_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, winner_id INTEGER references player(player_id),
 loser_id INTEGER references player(player_id));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add cast operator to the query i.e. COUNT(match.winner_id)::int and COUNT(match.loser_id + match.winner_id)::int. Otherwise you will have to cast the column in the resultset.

```
db_cursor.execute("""SELECT player.player_id, player.player_name, 
                       COUNT(match.winner_id)::int as wins, COUNT(match.loser_id + match.winner_id)::int as total_matches
                       FROM player LEFT JOIN match ON player.player_id = match.winner_id
                       GROUP BY player.player_id
                       ORDER BY wins ASC""")
```